# Can't make crontab work

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu and I seldom have to use it. I am trying to make this PHP script to run every minute using cron, but firstly I wanted to make some tests.

I created an empty file at `/var/www/html/` called `test`. I ran on terminal:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And added this line:

```
0 * * * * rm /var/www/html/test
```

Then saved it and exited. It said "**Installing new Crontab**"

Nothing happened. Then I created a file bfile.sh that contained:

```
#!/bin/sh 
rm /var/www/html/test
```

and added the following to crontab:

```
0 * * * * bash /var/www/html/bfile.sh
```

Still nothing happened.

What do I have to do to see anything happening from crontab? By the way I checked and the service is running

Comment: Check the "debugging crontab" section in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info. Do you have permission to remove that file?

Comment: @fedorqui when I run `rm /var/www/html/filex` (not using sudo) it is removed

Comment: Your crontab entries run every HOUR, not every MINUTE. To run every minute, it should be `* * * * *`.

Comment: Questions about using `crontab` belong on linux.stackexchange.com, not SO.

Comment: Are the answers provided correct? You should accept one of them if yes

Answer (score 3):

`0 * * * *` basically says "run this at 0th minute of every hour."

If you need cron to run your command every minute do `* * * * *`.

Answer (score 3):

`0 * * * *` runs once every 1 hour. If you want to run every minute it should be `*/1 * * * *`

You can also check the /var/log/cron file for any errors